# Plot discrete density for a given cumulative distribution function

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I am given a discrete cumulative distribution function in the following form:

```
set.seed(1)
x  <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y  <- ecdf(x)(sort(x))
cdf <- data.table(x=sort(x),y=y)

str(cdf)
   Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
   $ x: num  -2.21 -1.99 -1.8 -1.52 -1.47 ...
   $ y: num  0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.1 ...
   - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I now would like to plot the a discrete density with ggplot. Concretely, I would like to have bar/Histogramm plot, where

1. the width of the bar is defined by the difference of x, respectively the bar goes from one x to the subsequent one
2. the height is given by the difference of the cumulative probability

So it would ressemble a step function

Answer (score 1):

Like this? I'm not sure what you mean by "height is give by the difference of the cumulative probability" since that seems to be 0.01 for all x.

```
library(dplyr)
cdf %>%
  arrange(x) %>%
  # The "default =" term below lets us assign a leftmost width (and thereby 
  #  display something for 100%) even though lead(x) is NA for the last row.
  mutate(x_next = lead(x, default = max(x) + 0.05),
         y_change = lead(y) - y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin = x, xmax = x_next,
             ymin = 0, ymax = y)) +
  geom_rect()
```

[image]